# How do I get Emacs projectile-mode to ignore most of the files that show up in a virtualenv Cython project?

Tags: emacs, ide, virtualenv, environment, projectile

I'm using Emacs on a virtualenv project with Cython files, and that means that most of the files are not ones I'm editing.  In particular, I don't want anything from the user subdir in the project.  So far no problems -- `-/usr` works in the `.projectile` file.  Now I want no `.c` files.  That doesn't work.  the documentation says that I should put `-*.c` in the `.projectile` file.  That doesn't work.  Neither does `-/foo/bar/*.c`, nor any other permutation I can think of.  Also, when the items in the `.projectile` file have slashes, the `find` command prints lots of warnings about paths with slashes.   Is there an Emacs Lisp way to do things that's better?  Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Looking at the documentation I suspect that you forgot to add a wildcard. It clearly states that `-*.c` should ignore all files with extension `c`.

Comment: Actually, that's a bug in the way I asked the question -- the - and wildcard were in the .projectile file.  Thanks for the good idea, though.  I wish the answer were that simple :-).

Comment: BTW, I edited my question to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edit -- looks much nicer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not enable "native indexing" (which is I believe disabled by default), Projectile ignores the contents of `.projectile` and uses `.gitignore`.

So either put `(setq projectile-indexing-method 'native)` in your `.emacs` file or populate `.gitignore`.

Comment: I see `Hybrid` mode working well for this, which probably has some advantages over `Native`.